# Stand Alone ROR App Security Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a Ruby on Rails-based website from which I want to create a stand-alone application (desktop app) so that users have an interface from their own computer without opening the browser and so that access is restricted to the people that have the app.

I am looking at the security of this and not sure how exactly to best go about this.

In a typical ROR site you have a `database.yml` file with your database information in it.

If I use `RubyScript2Exe` I think it would be too easy for someone to access this information. Maybe I am wrong.

My question is should I build this app as an API only thru my main site or should I build it to directly interface with the database.

One other option is to create its own database on each desktop computer to save their posts and an interface with the main database thru an api call.

My app will need to:

```
  Create New Records in Database
  Search Database
  Delete records created by user
```

Main site uses Devise for log-in authenication

Comment: I might be missing something here but why would you go through all the trouble to port your web application, which will apparently still exist, to a desktop application just to restrict access? I ask because what it seems you want to do works perfectly well via the web with gems like Devise (noted since you're already using it) and Pundit and others. This seems to me like overkill for the problem at hand but, again, I might be missing something (and, if so, apologies!).

Comment: If we use a distributed version of the site. it will decrease the load on the server. by using the users own processor to load and interface with the site. the only interaction would be database interaction.

Comment: Ok, cool ... figured there was a reason but wanted to clarify! Here are some resources: http://shoesrb.com (building a GUI in Ruby), http://www.rubymotion.com (using Ruby to build desktop/iOS apps). Never tried the RubyScript2Exe so cannot comment on it.